# A method that is called when the databases are updated via the admin panel

Tags: python, django, wagtail

the idea is that I will not need to, each time enter some data, the value of which depends on the value of other data. For example.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    1_score_team_1 = models.IntegerField()
    2_score_team_1 = models.IntegerField()
    1_score_team_2 = models.IntegerField()
    2_score_team_2 = models.IntegerField()
    total_score_of_team_1 = models.IntegerField()
    total_score_of_team_2 = models.IntegerField()
    def function:
        total_score_of_team_1 = 1_score_team_1 + 2_score_team_1
        total_score_of_team_2 = 1_score_team_2 + 2_score_team_2
    return update total score of two teams
```

This method should be called every time I enter data through the admin panel.

Comment: This is what [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @daniel-roseman for the link
I realized this as follows.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender='app_name.Example')
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
   instance.total_score_of_team_1 = instance.1_score_team_1 + instance.2_score_team_1
   instance.total_score_of_team_2 = instance.1_score_team_2 + instance.2_score_team_2
```